# Plugin OAuth2 do Spring Security com Tokens Json

Tags: json, xml, spring-security, oauth2

Alguem me pode dizer se o plugin OAuth2 do Spring Security suporta access tokens no formato JSON em vez do formato XML? E se sim o que é preciso fazer para fazer essa mudança?

Answer (score 1):

Sim, ele aceita. Por padrão ele ja te retorna um JSON. Em algumas versões mais novas do Spring OAuth2 ele exige que você configure um padrão de retorno no Spring. Depende muito da versão do Spring Framework e do Spring Security OAuth2.

A configuração padrão que eu tenho agora, usando java, config é:

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
                    .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}
```